# Can I classify various spatial patterns using k-mean clustering?

Tags: python, python-3.x, k-means

I would like to classify several spatial patterns into four types using K-clustering. For example, if I have 40 spatial patterns, I would divide them into A, B, C, and D patterns, 12 with A pattern, 8 with B pattern, 10 and 10 with C and D.

Patterns have data values in a two-dimensional space (with np.shape, it has a structure of (40,18,81)). Can I classify the 40 patterns with each (18,81) structure as described above using k-mean clustering?

To help you understand, I'll show you some examples of the patterns I mentioned.
[[image: pattern_example]
[[image: Pattern_example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do that.  It would be like doing clustering on tabular data that has 18*81 = 1,458 dimensions (variables/columns) and 40 observations/rows.  Keep in mind that this algorithm only allows you to specify the number of clusters to create, not specify how many data points (patterns, in your case) to assign to each cluster.

You would likely need to flatten your 18*81 arrays into 1*1458 shape.

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that way. Thank you for your answer Alex.